# Express and Mongoose-failing to update an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to update an object by assigning it a new field, which is defined in the schema, like this:

```
exports.updatePlot = async (req, res) => {
    let modifications = {};
    modifications = Object.assign(modifications, req.body.props);
    const id = modifications.id;
    try {
        const updatedPlot = await Plot.findByIdAndUpdate(
            id,
            { $set: modifications },
            { new: true }
        );
        console.log(('updated  plot saved:', updatedPlot));
        res.json({
            updatedPlot
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
        return res.status(422).send({
            error: { message: 'e', resend: true }
        });
    }
};
```

This works when I modify existing fields. However, when I try to add a new field (which is defined in the Mongoose schema, but does not exist in the object in the database), it fails. Meaning, there is no error, but the new field is not added.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you don't need to use $set. `Plot.findByIdAndUpdate(query,body,options)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mongoose documentation of findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate)

- new: bool - true to return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false
- upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.

---

You are mistaking **new** with **upsert**

---

Moreover as @Rahul Sharma said and looking at mongoose documentation example, you do not need to use $set

[image]

Comment: I want the modified document returned, though.

Comment: So use both, new and upsert. like `{ new: true, upsert: true }`

Comment: I don't want to create a new object if it doesn't exist.